Driving a 74LS gate with a 4000-series output
I'm making a PCB based on a schematic I found online. On the schematic, a diode AND gate takes in signals from a 74LS298 multiplexer and a 4520 binary counter and outputs to a 74LS86.
Since I've added a 74LS08 (quad AND gates) for a modification elsewhere in the schematic, I would like to use one of its gates in place of the diode logic to reduce the amount of components needed.

Will I run into any problems with this configuration? This AND gate is the only thing on the schematic that is driven by the 4520.
For those interested, this is a schematic for the Leningrad-1, a Soviet ZX Spectrum clone (hence the Soviet part numbers above schematic symbols). The full schematic can be found here: https://sblive.narod.ru/ZX-Spectrum/Leningrad48k/LeningradSCH180dpi.gif

If we take this datasheet as representative of your 4520, the part is guaranteed to be able to sink 420uA up to Tj=85°C with a 5V Vdd.
Since a 74LS input requires the driver to sink only 400uA to register as a low with normal noise immunity you should be fine unless you're planning on using this in extreme conditions.
Of course there could be differences in timing that would scupper your plan, but that's outside the scope of this answer.

Actually, it needs a pullup on the output of the LSS08. LS isn't actually guaranteed to pull higher than Vih for 74LS chips, which is 2.4 volts. Given a 5 volt supply this is an obvious problem. Much more typical of an LS output is about 4 volts unloaded, so it will almost always work - but if it doesn't you have no one to blame. (Note, I just checked the Fairchild 74LS04, and that give Voh(min) as 2.7 volts. Still not a good idea.) Typically for LS a 10K is adequate.

@WhatRoughBeast  Not the subject of the question or this answer, but I agree. Almost always work can be worse than not working at all.  Of course  using an HC08 or HCT08 would deal with both questions but it might introduce problems elsewhere.

@greybeard - Sorry, I had a brain-fart. Although the question asked about 4000 driving LS, I was referring to LS driving 4000. An LS high input is actually providing current, so this is not an issue LS to LS. But an LS ouput driving a 4000 input will not (necessarily) provide the high voltage required. Sorry for the confusion. My apologies.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany - You are right, of course. What can I say? Must be the season for brain farts. Maybe too much turkey at Christmas. My answer is perfectly correct - it just doesn't answer the question that was actually asked.

It's not going to get worse if you make this change.
The existing 74LS86N needs more input current than the new 74LS08 so installing that will improve the operating current margins.
Deleting the diodes with improve operating voltage margins, so it's improvements all round.

Generally going from a 4000 series output to a single 74LS series input is fine, when you want to feed more than one input, loading can become a problem.
The 74HCT series can be a useful bridge family as it has TTL compatible input thresholds, low input loading and powerful output drivers.

On the other hand, 74HC will be cheaper and will work just fine since it is being fed by CMOS levels rather than TTL levels, so no TTL compatibility required. The HCT series has a standard CMOS output, it's only the input that changes.

Sure, but we don't know what the other gates are being used for. The great thing about HCT is it can sit between TTL and traditional CMOS in either direction. It's also useful for boosting 3.3V stuff up to 5V. Altogether a very flexible family. Price difference seems negligable at least for DIL parts from mouser.
